# How to transfer files from windows into kali linux live usb

Tags: windows-8.1, kali-linux

How to copy a file into kali linux live usb from windows so that it can show up when i boot kali as live??? Sorry if the question is absurd. I have a internet problem but I do have the file in my Windows, but I need it in kali linux live to use it. How to copy it?? I'm a newbie and i want to learn how to use kali linux more efficiently, so i'm sorry if the question is awkward.

Answer (score 0):

You should partition your usb drive. One partition will be used for kali linux; the other will be formatted as storage drive and will be accessible from kali while running live.

Comment: Ooh! So i do have to create a partition to copy files. So the storage partition will be used as typical usb but shows files both in kali linux live and windows right??

Comment: The storage partition will be accessible both from windows and from kali. Note that if you run kali live on the pc on which is installed windows, you can mount the windows hard disk and copy the windows files in the storage partition on the usb